Change ieeeaccess to single column format
I have to use the ieeeaccess template for a journal article, but the journal asked me to include a single column format as well. The ieeeaccess template forces two columns and does not respond to one column commands as the IEEEtrans formatting does.
What's the easiest way to get the document to onecolumn and while keeping the rest of the ieeeaccess formatting?
Link to IEEE Access guidelines and template (https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/guide-for-authors/submission-guidelines/)
